# Time frame extraction in R

Tags: r, time

### I have a dataset which looks like the following:

```
    date    time_interval
    1050901 00:01~01:00
    1050901 01:01~02:00
    1050901 02:01~03:00
    .. ..
    1051231 23:01~24:00
```

### I want to create the new variable indicating the starting time and the ending time, for example

```
    date    time_interval  starting_time     ending_time
    1050901 00:01~01:00    2016 Sep 1 00:01  2016 Sep 1 01:00
    1050901 01:01~02:00    2016 Sep 1 01:01  2016 Sep 1 02:00
    1050901 02:01~03:00    2016 Sep 1 02:01  2016 Sep 1 03:00
    ....
    1051231 23:01~24:00    2016 Dec 31 23:01 2016 Dec 31 24:00
```

How should I extract the first and the second values in the second column and aggregate it with the first column? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `strsplit(time_interval, "~")`, which gives a list, then `sapply(thatlist, "[", 1)` for first time bit, `sapply(thatlist, "[", 2)` for second.

Comment: How does the date '1050901` translate to 2016?

Comment: I guess 105 = 2016 - 1911 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minguo_calendar), the other digits are %m%d.

Comment: Thanks for Bergant's explanation. You are right. However, I still didn't quite get it. Would Remko please explain more? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out.